# Vertical bundles of higher order tangent bundles

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, classical-mechanics

Let $M$ be a smooth (finite dimensional, Hausdorff and second countable) manifold. Let $T^kM$ be the manifold of equivalence class of curves that their derivates (in charts) agree up to order $k$. Let $j^k_0\gamma \in T^kM $ denote the equivalence class of $\gamma$.

Then the following maps are surjective submersions:
$$ \pi^k_r:T^kM \longrightarrow T^rM, \;\; k\geq r$$
$$ j^k_0\gamma \mapsto j^r_0\gamma $$
Obviously $\pi^k_s=\pi^r_s\circ \pi^k_r $ for $k\geq r\geq s$.

**Question**: Is there a canonical way to describe the vertical bundle $V\pi^k_r:=\ker T\pi^k_r$ in terms of the spaces $T^sM$ and $T(T^sM)$?

We can do it easily in the case of $r=k-1$ as the map:
$$ \pi^k_{k-1}:T^kM \longrightarrow T^{k-1}M$$
It's an affine bundle with associated vector bundle $T^{k-1}M \times_M TM \longrightarrow T^{k-1}M$. Then we have the canonical isomorphism:
$$ \mathfrak J: T^kM\times_M TM \longrightarrow V\pi^k_{k-1}$$
$$ (j^k_0\gamma, v) \mapsto \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} (j^k_0\gamma+tv), \;\; v\in T_{\gamma(0)}M $$

I found myself an extension that Crampin gaves (in [Higher-order differential equations and higher-order lagrangian mechanics](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=&s5=Higher-order%20differential%20equations%20and%20higher-order%20lagrangian%20mechanics&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq)) for the case $r=0$ (or $r=k$ in the following notation):
$$ \mathfrak J: T^kM\times_{T^{r-1}M} T(T^{r-1}M) \longrightarrow V\pi^k_{k-r}$$
$$ (j^k_0 \chi_0,\frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0}j^{r-1}_0\chi_s)\mapsto \frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0}j^k_0\hat \chi_s $$
For any smooth map $\chi:\mathbb R^2 \longrightarrow M$, $\chi_s(t):=\chi(s,t)$, $\hat\chi_s(t):=\chi(st^{k-r+1},t) $. These are well defined isomorphism.

I'm looking for a more geometric equivalent description of these map more similar to the affine case $r=k-1$.